# Dynamic test tag pattern execution in karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, automation-testing

[image]i have to run selected tests in karate using test runner and tags, apart from using the method like this- tags("SMOKE", "Regression"), can we have an alternative in java where the tags can be dynamically executed instead of manually using the tags in testrunner?

this is my test runner attached.

Comment: please assume that this is not supported. if you are lucky, the linked answer may give you a solution